# Get an image from web content folder outside web project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

**The objective**

I have 2 projects at the same solution and the objective is to Get an image from web project on domain project.

1. Project.web ("web application") *"here's the image /Content/Images"*
2. Project.domain ("All domain entities") *"I want to take it from here!!"*

**The problem**
I was trying to read from my Web "Content/Images" folder  but I don't know how to set the url and if that's possible to do.

The ugly and dirty code that works is this: but I don't want to fix the image on a folder>

```
Image logo = Image.FromFile(@"c:\folder\img.png");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize that when you deploy your application in IIS there's no longer a notion of *other projects*. So you should include this image as part of your ASP.NET application. You could have for example a post-build compilation step which copies the image from your `Project.domain` to your ASP.NET MVC application (for example inside the `App_Data` folder) so that inside your MVC application you will be able to use the Server.MapPath method to access the image:

```
using (var image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/img.png")))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: OOkey darin thank's for your response!!! in case that I cut the image from project.domain and then copy the image on project.web > App_Data, how I could read it on project.domain?? because Server.MapPath hehehe is not working! :(

Comment: You could leave the image in your Project.Domain and have a custom post-compilation step that will copy it to the Project.Web. But what is `Project.Domain`? Is it a class library? If so, then have your method taking the path to the image as parameter and then this parameter will be passed from the Web project and calculated using the Server.MapPath method.

Comment: Yes it's a class library that creates excel files and I need to paste an image inside :) I've seeeeeeeeeeeeen the light ! ( Send By Parameter the URL of the image on the constructor of the CLASS using there Server.MapPath!!! :D ) TY Darin !!! :)

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time searching for **Server** variable, enjoy! :)

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetRenderImage(long id, int size = 0)
    {
        // Load template           
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/media/template.png"); 
        WebImage img = new WebImage(file);

        // some operations with image, for sample scale or crop
        ...

        // get image data
        var bytes = img.GetBytes("image/jpeg");

        // Save to blob
        var p = getCloudBlobContainer("RenderImg");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = p.GetBlockBlobReference(String.Format("{0}.jpg", id);
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        var url = blob.Uri.ToString();

        // Redirect to Azure blob image
        return Redirect(url);
    }
```